# Converting circular structure to JSON (webpack + apexcharts)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, apexcharts

I'm getting this error on `yarn serve`:

```
WAIT  Compiling...                                                                                                                  11:14:16 AM

98% after emitting

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                               11:15:03 AM

 error

Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'NormalModule'
    |     property 'dependencies' -> object with constructor 'Array'
    |     index 0 -> object with constructor 'HarmonyCompatibilityDependency'
    --- property 'originModule' closes the circle
```

(*this error happens while yarn is still open - not a full crash*)

Or somethimes `yarn` crashes entirely with :

```
90% additional chunk assets processing HotModuleReplacementPluginC:\PATH\TO\MY\PROJECT\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\ModuleTemplate.js:85
                        throw e;
                        ^

TypeError: C:\PATH\TO\MY\PROJECT\client\node_modules\cache-loader\dist\cjs.js??ref--13-0!C:\PATH\TO\MY\PROJECT\client\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js!C:\PATH\TO\MY\PROJECT\client\node_modules\eslint-loader\index.js??ref--14-0!C:\PATH\TO\MY\PROJECT\client\src\js\routes\models\virtuals\index.js
Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'NormalModule'
    |     property 'dependencies' -> object with constructor 'Array'
    |     index 0 -> object with constructor 'HarmonyCompatibilityDependency'
    --- property 'originModule' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at requireChunkId (C:\PATH\TO\MY\PROJECT\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\RuntimeTemplate.js:320:35)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at RuntimeTemplate.blockPromise (C:\PATH\TO\MY\PROJECT\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\RuntimeTemplate.js:322:6)
    at RuntimeTemplate.moduleNamespacePromise (C:\PATH\TO\MY\PROJECT\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\RuntimeTemplate.js:136:24)
    at ImportDependencyTemplate.apply (C:\PATH\TO\MY\PROJECT\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\ImportDependency.js:22:27)
    at JavascriptGenerator.sourceDependency (C:\PATH\TO\MY\PROJECT\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\JavascriptGenerator.js:151:12)
    at JavascriptGenerator.sourceBlock (C:\PATH\TO\MY\PROJECT\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\JavascriptGenerator.js:44:9)
    at JavascriptGenerator.sourceBlock (C:\PATH\TO\MY\PROJECT\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\JavascriptGenerator.js:133:9)
    at JavascriptGenerator.generate (C:\PATH\TO\MY\PROJECT\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\JavascriptGenerator.js:23:8)
    at NormalModule.source (C:\PATH\TO\MY\PROJECT\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:522:33)
    at ModuleTemplate.render (C:\PATH\TO\MY\PROJECT\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\ModuleTemplate.js:54:32)
    at C:\PATH\TO\MY\PROJECT\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\Template.js:233:28
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.renderChunkModules (C:\PATH\TO\MY\PROJECT\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\Template.js:230:30)
    at HotUpdateChunkTemplate.render (C:\PATH\TO\MY\PROJECT\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\HotUpdateChunkTemplate.js:48:34)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

#### Context

I have one web application, SPA(`laravel-enso`), Laravel + VueJs.
In GIT in the `develop` branch, we do **not** have `apexcharts` installed and integrated. Another branch called `upgrade` has `apexcharts` installed:
client/package.json

```
"serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port 8082 --mode development",
"build": "vue-cli-service build --no-clean",
...
"dependencies": {
    "apexcharts": "^3.35.0",
    ...
    "vue3-apexcharts": "^1.4.1",
}
...
```

In the `upgrade` branch I have one vue component called `RrdGraph` that makes use of `apexcharts` :

```
import VueApexCharts from "vue3-apexcharts";

export default {
    name: 'RrdGraph',
    components: {
        apexchart: VueApexCharts,
    },

...

connectionSeries: [
            {
                name: "Current",
                data: [],
            },
            {
                name: "Total",
                data: [],
            },
            {
                name: "Request",
                data: [],
            },
        ],

        connectionChartOptions: {
            chart: {
                id: 'connectionChart',
                group: 'network',
                width: 800,
                background: '#fff',
                // zoom: {
                //     autoScaleYaxis: false, //not supported on multi-axis
                // },
                animations: {
                    enabled: false,
                },
                stacked: false,
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    columnWidth: '30%',
                    rangeBarOverlap: false,
                },
            },
            markers: {
                size: 0,
                style: 'hollow',
                colors: [
                    '#00af00', //Current / 0
                    '#0022ff', //New (Total) / 1
                    '#000000', //Request / 4
                ],
            },
            stroke: {
                width: [3, 3, 2],
                colors: [
                    '#00af00', //Current / 0
                    '#0022ff', //New (Total) / 1
                    '#000000', //Request / 4
                ],
                // lineCap: 'square',
                curve: 'straight', //'smooth', 'straight', 'stepline'
            },
            fill: {
                opacity: 1,
            },
            xaxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                min: new Date(Date.now()).getTime() - 31536000, //1 year
                tickAmount: 10,
            },
            yaxis:
                [
                    {
                        seriesName: 'Current',
                        showAlways: true,
                        axisTicks: {
                            show: true,
                        },
                        axisBorder: {
                            show: true,
                            color: '#0000FF',
                        },
                        labels: {
                            show: true,
                            style: {
                                colors: '#0000FF',
                            },
                        },
                        markers: {
                            colors: '#0000FF',
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: "Current & Total",
                            style: {
                                color: '#0000FF',
                            },
                        },
                        type: 'numeric',
                        decimalsInFloat: 1,
                        tickAmount: 10,
                    },
                    {
                        seriesName: 'Current',
                        showAlways: true,
                        axisTicks: {
                            show: false,
                        },
                        axisBorder: {
                            show: false,
                        },
                        labels: {
                            show: false,
                        },
                        type: 'numeric',
                        decimalsInFloat: 1,
                        tickAmount: 10,
                    },
                    {
                        seriesName: 'Request',
                        showAlways: true,
                        opposite: false,
                        axisTicks: {
                            show: true,
                        },
                        axisBorder: {
                            show: true,
                            color: '#000000',
                        },
                        labels: {
                            show: true,
                            style: {
                                colors: '#000000',
                            },
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: "Request (per 5 min)",
                            style: {
                                color: '#000000',
                            },
                        },
                        type: 'numeric',
                        decimalsInFloat: 1,
                        tickAmount: 10,
                    },
                ],
            tooltip: {
                x: {
                    format: 'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss',
                },
                // followCursor: true,
                // fixed: {
                //     enabled: true,
                //     position: 'topRight',
                //     offsetX: 5,
                //     offsetY: 25,
                // },
            },
            legend: {
                horizontalAlign: 'center',
                fontSize: '12px',
                offsetX: -100,
                offsetY: 5,
            },
            colors: [
                '#00af00', //Current / 0
                '#0022ff', //Total / 1
                '#000000', //Request / 4
            ],
        },
```

Initially I looked at this error as a very generic one, and I looked into `package.json` `dependencies` and `devDependencies` and if there are circular references. But I saw no issues with the dependencies of either `apexcharts` or `vue3-apexcharts`.

I've also observer that `yarn build` was working and only `yarn serve` was not. Looking deeper into what `build` and `serve` were doing, I saw that the `--mode development` was generating the error - since if I added `--mode development` to `yarn build` params it was crashing.

One important fact, that made me think this is related to `apexcharts` was that on the `develop` branch (the one that did not have `apexcharts` installed) `yarn serve` was not generating this error. And these 3 things were the only differences (RrdGraph compoenent and the 2 dependencies, `apexcharts` and `vue3-apexcharts`)

I started a long process of *divide and conquer* by removing bits and pieces from my `RrdGraph` component that used `apexcharts`.

I removed and removed, each time checking what part of the code was generating the error, and which removed part was not generating the error.

I reached this part:

```
plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    horizontal: false,
                    borderRadius: 0,
                    columnWidth: '30%',
                    // barHeight: '50%',
                    distributed: false,
                    rangeBarOverlap: false,
                    rangeBarGroupRows: false,
                },
            },
```

If I removed this part. Yarn was working again, no errors!

I tried to associated this with something and thought that if I remove the lines with bar options that are default values anyways, it is working - like this:

```
plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    columnWidth: '30%',
                    rangeBarOverlap: false,
                },
            },
```

(these being the only actual changes that we wanted that are not default values)

I thought that was it, since it was working again.

But then, the next one hit me harder:

We changed some comments in these options, so instead of `//Total / 1` we changed it to `//New (Total) / 1`:

```
markers: {
                size: 0,
                style: 'hollow',
                colors: [
                    '#00af00', //Current / 0
                    '#0022ff', //New (Total) / 1
                    '#000000', //Request / 4
                ],
            },
            stroke: {
                width: [3, 3, 2],
                colors: [
                    '#00af00', //Current / 0
                    '#0022ff', //New (Total) / 1
                    '#000000', //Request / 4
                ],
```

This made `yarn serve` crash again :(

Interestingly, it was only the first comment within `markers`, not the one within `stroke` that made it crash.

Conclusions:
I have no idea what is happening and why it behaves like this.
It might be also something related to `webpack` and what it converts these options to JSON.
It might be something related to how the options are passed to the component or, how this is converted to JSON in the `--mode development`, but something is strange

I'm wondering if someone had this issue or could share some hints.

Comment: PS: I've opened a question on github too : https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/discussions/3317

Comment: You will have to run Vue CLI directly instead of through a script in package.json - e.g. `node --inspect-brk node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js serve` and then put a breakpoint on line 320 in `webpack\lib\RuntimeTemplate.js`. Thus you will see in DevTools what is the exact Object that `requireChunkId ` is trying to serialize to JSON - and hopefully investigate why there are circular references.

Comment: @IVOGELOV thanks for your input. I tried what you suggested and, unfortunately, the problem has 2 sides. One side crashes with just 
```Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'NormalModule'
    |     property 'dependencies' -> object with constructor 'Array'
    |     index 0 -> object with constructor 'HarmonyCompatibilityDependency'
    --- property 'originModule' closes the circle
```
and other times it crashed with full yarn stop, and showed full trace. 
Most of my tests and debugging that I've done, did not fail on `RuntimeTemplate.js`

Comment: I'll try to figure out how to see a trace and debug that part of the code. Error happens `98% after emitting` this means after `95% emitting HtmlWebpackPlugin` and after the `webpack\lib\RuntimeTemplate.js`

Comment: I've tracked down the error to this file: `/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js` and when this is called `this.compiler.hooks.done.callAsync(...` this file is called `node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js` and then this function `createCompileDelegate(name, type) { return function lazyCompileHook(` and somewhere here it goes sideways trying to print the error with `node_modules/@soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin/src/friendly-errors-plugin.js` - with these args `0: "\u001b[41m\u001b[30m ERROR \u001b[39m\u001b[49m \u001b[31mFailed to compile with 1 error..."`

Comment: This type of debugging is not fun because sometimes some NPM packages start new Node processes which of course no longer have the `--inspect-brk` command-line option. If you can't put a breakpoint somewhere or it does not fire - you can instead edit the source file inside `node_modules` and insert a `debugger;` statement. But not a fun - it is too much code on too many layers.